# solving a second order ode $\lambda f''+f=2f(1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this ODE, with $\lambda\neq 0$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$:

$$\lambda f''+f=2f(1),$$

with $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=\int_{0}^{1}f(y)dy$. I also have $f'(1)=\frac{f(1)}{\lambda}$, but I don't know if helps.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi :) it's a linear inhomogeneous ode. Its homogeneous solution is $f_h(x)=a\sin(x\lambda^{-1/2}) + b\cos(x\lambda^{-1/2})$ because the eigenvalues are $\pm i \lambda^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Linear Oscillator with a source.

Comment: Where is the problem from? It is not so straightforward because the 'constant' on the RHS depends upon the solution $f$. I suggest differentiating the expression, solving the resulting third order ODE, then fixing the constants using your boundary conditions *and* initial equation

Answer (score 3):

Since $f(1)$ is just a constant, why don't you apply the usual procedure for solving ODE like $a y''(x) + b y(x) = c$?

In this case $a = \lambda$, $b = 1$ and $c = \lambda f(1)$, hence the general solution reads:

$$f(x)\to c_1 \cos \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right)+c_2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right)+ \lambda f(1)$$

Then $f(0) = 0$ means $c_1 = -\lambda f(1)$ hence from here

$$f(x)\to \lambda f(1)\left(1- \cos \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right)\right)+c_2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right)$$

We check now $f'(1) = \lambda^{-1} f(1)$:

$$f'(x) = \frac{\lambda f(1) \sin \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right)+c_2 \cos \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$$

Which makes me think

$$c_2 = \dfrac{\dfrac{f(1)}{\lambda} - \lambda f(1) \sin\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right)}{\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right)}$$

Comment: There is some way to know a family of $\lambda$ who satisfaties this? Because my initial problem is to find $\lambda$ who satisfaties $Tf=\lambda f$

Comment: @LuizaSilva So you have an eigenvalues equation. In this case, since this question is rather "different" from your initial one, I suggest you to take what you need from here, and create a new question (without deleting this) where you exactly show your problem, that is writing what you told me now, define what is $T$ and so on. A new clear question!

Comment: I thought that my computation was wrong because the eigenvalue shoudn't be so complicated to find... sorry for the inconvenient

Comment: Is your solution consistent with $f(1)=f(1)$?